# Problems with C++ red-black tree implementation

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree, red-black-tree

I'm trying to make a C++ implementation of RB tree. But when I try to delete an element - I find out that some leaves of tree has different value of black height. Before calling remove functions everything works fine - insertion and rebalancing after tree insertion works correctly. But after a single call of remove function it isn't balanced anymore.

General remove:

```
void RbTree::remove(int data) {
Node* cur = root;
while (cur != nil && cur->data != data) { // Searching for node with expected key
    if (cur->data < data)
        cur = cur->RIGHT;
    else
        cur = cur->LEFT;
    if (cur == nil) 
        return;
}
removeNode(cur); // Recurrent BST node removing

RbTree::Node* RbTree::removeNode(Node*& cur) {
    if (cur->RIGHT == nil && cur->LEFT == nil) { // No children
        Node* dad = cur->ancestor;
        if (cur == root) { // If current node is root
            cur = root = nil;
        }     else { // Dad now points to nil
            if (cur->color == BLACK)
            fixRemoving(cur);
        dad->RIGHT == cur ? dad->RIGHT = nil : dad->LEFT = nil; 
    }
} else if (!(cur->RIGHT != nil && cur->LEFT != nil)) { // If there's only one children for current node
    Node* dad = cur->ancestor;
    Node* son;
    cur->RIGHT != nil ? son = cur->RIGHT : son = cur->LEFT; // Searching for son
    dad->RIGHT == cur ? dad->RIGHT = son : dad->LEFT = son; // Dad now points to son
    son->ancestor = dad;
    son->color = BLACK; // Changing son's color
    if (cur->color == BLACK) {
        fixRemoving(son);
    }
} else { // If left and right child exist
    Node* found = findMin(cur->RIGHT); // Finding the least element in right subtree
    cur->data = found->data; // Copying data
    removeNode(found); // Recurrently remove found node
}
return cur;
```

Fix removing function:

```
void RbTree::fixRemoving(Node*& node) {
Node* dad = node->ancestor;
Node* bro;
if (node == dad->LEFT) {
    bro = dad->RIGHT;
    if (bro->color == RED) {
        bro->color = BLACK;
        dad->color = RED;
        leftRotate(dad);
        bro = dad->RIGHT;
    }
    Node* leftNephew = bro->LEFT;
    Node* rightNephew = bro->RIGHT;
    if (leftNephew->color == BLACK && rightNephew->color == BLACK) { // 1) If both of bro's children are black
        bro->color = RED;
        dad->color = BLACK; 
        fixRemoving(dad);
        return;

    } else if (leftNephew->color == RED) { // 2) Else if only left is red - we need to make those steps and go to 3)
        leftNephew->color = BLACK;
        bro->color = RED;
        rightRotate(bro); 
    }
    rightNephew->color = BLACK; // 3) Now left nephew is black and right is red
    bro->color = dad->color;
    dad->color = BLACK;
    leftRotate(dad);
} else { // Same things there
    bro = dad->LEFT;
    if (bro->color == RED) {
        bro->color = BLACK;
        dad->color = RED;
        rightRotate(dad);
        bro = dad->LEFT;
    }
    Node* leftNephew = bro->LEFT;
    Node* rightNephew = bro->RIGHT;
    if (leftNephew->color == BLACK && rightNephew->color == BLACK) {
        bro->color = RED;
        dad->color = BLACK;
        fixRemoving(dad);
        return;
    } else if (leftNephew->color == RED) {
        leftNephew->color = BLACK;
        bro->color = RED;
        rightRotate(bro);
    }
    rightNephew->color = BLACK;
    bro->color = dad->color;
    dad->color = BLACK;
    rightRotate(dad);
}
```

I guess that I might have problems with:

1. calling fixRemoving function with right node argument
2. the body of fixRemoving method

An algorithm that I'm using:

1. Find a node that we want to remove like we would do it in common BST.
2. If it has no children - just remove it, if it has only 1 children - we place this child instead of removable node, coloring it black.
3. If it has both children - we find the least element in right subtree and recurrently removing him.
4. If original color of a node was black - then we need to fix a tree.

Fixing algorithm is described in code - there's no extra information needed, I hope.

Please, help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mostly agree with your algorithm.
But I disagree with attempting to fix a node when only 1-child.
Once you found the node to delete - count its children
There are 3 situations where a deleting node is easy, cheap to do.
Those are

1. 0-children and the node is red => just delete it
2. 0-children and the node is the root node => just delete it
3. 1-child, all situations. The reality is the node to delete is black and the child red.
   The other 3 possibilities are all invalid Red-Black trees and so don't occur.
   The solution is delete the node, replace with the child, and make the child black.
   No other further fixup's are required.

For 2-children, you need to find either successor (right child then left as far as you can go) or predecessor (left child then right far as you can go).
This node will always be a 0 or 1 child case, it cannot be 2.
I would test to see if the successor/predecessor is a "cheap to delete" node and if not, choose the predecessor/successor. Your aiming to get a cheap delete.
You then need to swap the node to delete with the successor/predecessor BUT THE ORIGINAL COLOURS ARE PRESERVED. Having swapped the nodes (and I mean all the pointer links), your problem then reduces to deleting a node that has 0 to 1 child which may be easy.

So what is left?

That is deleting a 0-children node, a leaf node, the colour is black and it is not the root node. This is the case that requires fixups, no other case requires fixups.